# How to use crosswalk embed XWalkView with aar library

Tags: android, gradle, crosswalk

I want to use `crosswalk` embed  `XWalkView` with aar library.

When I import the `xwalk-core-library` project as a module for the main project my app is Executable.

But once I build the `xwalk-core-library` project as aar library by maven and import by main project my app crashes. The log says `Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode`.

All I need `XWalkView` with activity instead of `XWalkActivity`.

I don't why this is happening? How to embed `XWalkView` to my app in aar form without including `XWalkActivity`?

Comment: add the gradle code + your activity code in your Q

Comment: I have the exact same issue only one some devices. (Samsung Galaxy s6 for example).

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I am having a similar issue. For me it is happening only in Android 7 devices though... No idea why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294582/android-xwalk-crash-after-oreo-migration

Answer (score 0):

Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode

I found the cause of this problem because there is no load the library file。